# what algorithm does git merge use for pattern matching?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, pattern-matching

I need to find commonalities and differences between two strings the same way that git merge does where all the parts that match stay the same, and all the places where there are differences are annotated. What algorithm does git use when resolving merges to accomplish this?

Comment: It's probably [one of these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Relationship_with_other_edit_distance_metrics).

Comment: See http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.608.1614&rep=rep1&type=pdf  and the reader's digest version here: http://search.cpan.org/~tyemq/Algorithm-Diff-1.1903/lib/Algorithm/Diff.pm